# Initialize size of vector of vectors

Tags: c++, vector

How do I declare a vector of size 30 with 30 empty vectors. I've tried

```
vector< vector<T> > vec(30);
```

But it returns with errors:

```
./HashSet.h:62:28: error: expected parameter declarator
         vector< vector<T> > table(30);
                              ^
./HashSet.h:62:28: error: expected ')'
./HashSet.h:62:27: note: to match this '('
    vector< vector<T> > table(30);
```

Comment: Always post the errors you get.

Comment: Not only what errors, what is `T`?

Comment: The declaration shown should create a vector containing 30 empty vectors of `T`.

Comment: The code looks alright. Please tell us which errors you get, most of us don't have experience with crystal balls.

Comment: T is just a templated class

Comment: If T is templated itself, then why aren't you passing template arguments?

Comment: `vector< vector<T> > vec; vec.resize(30);` ?

Comment: When posting code, please post *actual* code, or as real as possible. Is it possible that `vec` is a member variable? Do you forgot to pass the template parameters to `T`? Missing a semicolon somewhere before this declaration? C++ can be hard enough to parse even with context, but without context it becomes *impossible*!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This creates a vector of 30 vectors of 30 elements each:

```
vector< vector<T> > vec(30, vector<T>(30));
```

But it requires that T is default-constructible.

Comment: I believe OP wants 30 empty vectors, but has a weird way of phrasing it.